# cocoa touch framework missing symbol called

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, cocoapods

I have a framework that depends on a couple of pods such as IQKeyboardManagerSwift, It used to work fine when I generate framework file and integrate it in a project that has the required pods installed. however, after updating cocoapods to version 1.11.2 the app that has the framework crashes with signal sigabrt from the framework on the first line that uses any of the pods, and the console prints

[image]

I've tried to revert back to cocoapods 1.10.1 but the crash keeps happening! I tried to change the linker flags options, framework path, header path, and it didn't work

Any ideas how to solve this issue or how to investigate it?

Comment: It might depend on wether or not the computer that runs the simulator has an M1 chip. I suggest that you test it on a non M1 computer just to rule that out. Another option is to right-click the xCode icon, choose "Get Info" and select "Open using Rosetta"

Comment: @ArikSegal unfortunately it's not the case..  I'm working on an intel macbook pro

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: This can happen if the compiled framework's library differs from the linked library.

Comment: @SayedObaid any updates on the issue?

Answer (score 0):

For me this was an issue with the **RealSwift** pod, going back to version **10.20.0** solved it for me

Comment: any idea why that happens?

Comment: @RomanBugaian I guess they introduced a breaking change

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when any pods code implementation syntax changes in new version or pod name changes, you need to check migration of that pod for code level changes or you can also downgrade the particular pod if you don't want to change the current code.